# easy_install: No such file or directory when installing Pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid

I am trying to setup **Python** then **Pyramid**. I am trying it from [here](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/quick_tutorial/requirements.html)

So I tried

```
$VENV/bin/easy_install "pyramid==1.5.7"
```

But its giving me error

```
/home/user/phyton_projects/env/bin/easy_install: No such file or directory
```

But **easy_install** is present in **/home/user/phyton_projects/env/bin/**.

Any solution??

Comment: I am doing it on ubuntu.

Comment: Try to `sudo chmod +x /home/user/phyton_projects/env/bin/easy_install` and then try again.

Comment: Disclaimer: `chmod +x` makes a file executable

Comment: Em, any chance you are misspelling `phyton` for `python`?

Comment: Running along with the python typo, what's the output of `ls -l /home/user/phyton_projects/env/bin/easy_install`?

Comment: @AvihooMamka it gives me chmod: cannot access `/home/vilas/phyton_projects/env/bin/easy_install`: No such file or directory

Comment: @AlexHall it gives `ls: cannot access /home/user/phyton_projects/env/bin/easy_install: No such file or directory` 
and `ls -l /home/user/phyton_projects/env/bin/` gives list including **easy_install**

Comment: Paste the whole line containing `easy_install` because it has potentially useful info. That's why we used `-l`. Also your path changed in resonse to AvihooMamka, now it's `/home/vilas/...`. What's going on?

Comment: The Quick Tutorial recommends that you set an environment variable `$VENV`. It is clear from the error that you set that value to be equal to `/home/user/phyton_projects/env`. Assuming that the value should include the proper spelling of "python": (1) try resetting the value of $VENV with `export VENV=/home/user/python_projects/env`. (2) Make sure you are in the correct working directory: `cd /home/user/python_projects`. (3) Install Pyramid with `$VENV/bin/easy_install "pyramid==1.5.7"`

Comment: Done!! Thanks all...